# ssh - sshfs difference

Tags: ssh, sshfs

There exists a difference when using ssh and sshfs.
My user is a root at the ssh client and it works when using ssh.

But I wanna use sshfs (due to some development issues). When using sshfs with the same user, I cannot access certain directories, which are requiring root privileges.

concerning ls -la:

www-data in ssh is displayed as 33 in sshfs.
root in ssh is displayed as wheel in sshfs.

ssh

```
drwxrwx--- 11 www-data root     4096 May  9 9:34 file
```

sshfs

```
drwxrwx--- 11 33 wheel     4096 May  9 9:34 file
```

Are the group dependencies to resolve?

EDIT: MacFUSE compatibility layer was installed on Mac OS X. The remote machine is an Ubuntu Linux. Are there another products required to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the UID & GID on the remote server don't match what you have locally. When you use ssh, everything works because you're on the remote system. When you use sshfs, you would have to map the remote UID/GID to your local system:

http://terokarvinen.com/mount_sshfs.html#no_write_permisson_files_owned_by_unkown_user